# Writing "Smith's (2020) paper" using natbib's citation commands

Tags: citing, natbib

Suppose that I want to write "Smith's (2020) paper" in LaTeX. I could try

```
\citet{smith}'s paper
```

but this will produce the wrong output, namely "Smith (2020)'s paper". In other words, the date will come before the apostrophe, not after it.

Is there any way to produce the sentence that I am after?

Many thanks in advance for any ideas or suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you use `natbib`'s `\citeauthor` and `\citeyear` macros.

```
\citeauthor{smith}'s (\citeyear{smith}) paper
```

If the `hyperref` package is loaded, the output of the two directives will both be hyperlinks to the associated formatted entry in the bibliography section.

Comment: `\citeauthor{elk}'s \citeyearpar{elk} paper` is one character longer but has the advantage that it responds to the parenthesis settings of `\citet`.

Comment: @moewe - Thanks! (I'd forgotten about `\citeyearpar`...)